# Laravel joining tables returns no data

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have 2 tables `orders` and `delivery_boys`. I have joined these 2 tables to get the delivery boy details

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::join('delivery_boys', 'delivery_boys.id', 'orders.delivery_boy_id')
        ->select('orders.id', 'name', 'phone_number', 'orders.address', 'orders.city', 'orders.pincode', 'delivery_time_slot', 'total', 'delivery_boys.name as delivery_boy')
        ->get();

    return view('pages.orders', compact('orders'));
}
```

I'm getting all the `orders` when there is data in `delivery_boy_id`, but if it is empty I'm not getting any data.

Initially when the order comes in, the `orders` tables `delivery_boy_id` will be empty. I want the data even if it is empty with join.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because by default `join` will produce an inner join. An inner join means that it will only retrieve the rows that has data on both sides.

What you're after is a left join:

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::leftJoin('delivery_boys', 'delivery_boys.id', 'orders.delivery_boy_id')
        ->select('orders.id', 'name', 'phone_number', 'orders.address', 'orders.city', 'orders.pincode', 'delivery_time_slot', 'total', 'delivery_boys.name as delivery_boy')
        ->get();

    return view('pages.orders', compact('orders'));
}
```

Alternatively, you could also just set up a relationship for this:

Assuming that you have a model for `delivery_boys` you would just need to add the following method to your `Order` Model:

```
public function deliveryBoy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(DeliveryBoy::class);
}
```

To get the orders:

```
$orders = Order::with('deliveryBoy')->get();
```

Lastly, to access information about the delivery boy:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {

    $order->deliveryBoy->name; //To get the delivery boy's name 
}
```

Hope this helps!